# Validity of HTML SELECT OPTION syntax

Tags: html, coding-style, html-select

For code readability I used to write `OPTION` tags in my `HTML` templates in such a multiline way:

*(It is a hypothetical web framework syntax, so it does not much matter and provided just to illustrate the reason of coding style. The question is about validity of rendered `HTML` syntax.)*

```xml
<option %attributes%>
  <%optionName%>
</option>
```

What later renders as:

```xml
<option value="1">
  Text 1
</option>
```

So, actual question (about this last snippet): Is that okay to have such `HTML` `<option>` code in the document? Or it will have potential hurdles?

Comment: How do you mean "it later renders as".
Do you mean the browser notices you're never supposed to put a `<span>` in an option and just returns its innerHTML? if so, then why would you go through the hassle of writing code the browser is going to throw away for you later?

Comment: Another one : how on earth does it get more readable if you add more (useless) code?

Comment: @Timothy Groote, thats ok with `<span>`, suppose, I use the [_Template Attribute Language_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Attribute_Language), there is such a feature as `tal:replace` which will replace `<span>` with certain data I pointed to, so it will as I showed in the example. I hid all template specifics under `%attributes%` clause. It could be not only `TAL` but other templating mechanisms..

Comment: Hmm, it seems kind of odd, counterintuitive even to do this.
Doesn't TAL just allow you to set the content property of the option explicitly?

Comment: Yes, `TAL` is flexible and I use `tal:content`, but what if the line `<option ...> ... </option>` becomes too long (incl. indents of the document) and it's uncomfortable to see in the editor..

Comment: The code posted under “What later renders as:” is valid HTML. The code above it is apparently not meant to be HTML at all, and would trivially be invalid if interpreted as HTML. So what is it that you are actually asking? When some templating system is involved, it should be mentioned in the question body and perhaps also in question title and/or tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `option` element may have any text as its content, so the construct is valid. Whether it is OK depends on your definition for OK and also on what you are doing on the page.

When there is leading or trailing whitespace (like line breaks and spaces) in the `option` content, they get included into the `innerHTML` and `textContent` properties of the element node, but not (according to [HTML5 drafts](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) and modern browser practice) not into the `text` property. The implied idea seems to be that leading or trailing whitespace does not affect rendering, but there does not seem to be any explicit statement on this.

So, it seems rather safe in practice (though perhaps not in theory), as long as you do not access the `innerHTML` or `textContent` property of the node or if you take due precautions when accessing them (that is, take into account that they have leading and trailing whitespace).